# Print item from char array?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I need to print a single character from a character array like as this one:

```
string DB 'ABC0','$'
```

I know I can print the whole string by doing this:

```
lea dx, string
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
```

How can I print just an individual character like for example "A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use int 21H/AH=02H

```
mov     dl, byte ptr[string]
mov     ah, 02h 
int     21h
```

`byte ptr` means you want, well, one byte from the variable/pointer.  To print the next letter, you just increment the pointer:

```
inc string
```

Comment: You usually have to declare it: inc w[string] kinda thing

Comment: You've got two problems to solve if you want an individual letter. DX only has the start pointer, which points at "A" so you will need to tweak the pointer forwards to the letter you want. Secondly your print function mov ah,A INT21h only blindly prints from the pointed letter to the $ terminator so you need an INT21 command which prints out a single character (usually loaded into AL)

Comment: `mov ah, 0Ah`/`int 21h` is buffered input, last I checked, and isn't going to print anything. Typo in the original post, I suspect.

Comment: @Frank, yes it works, why wouldn't it?  If the starting address of `string`/`a` is 100 then `b` is 101 right?  So an `inc string` increases the address.  In a loop, it prints just fine in DosBox and Emu386.

Comment: Ooookay... I would have said that it increments 'A' to 'B' - same result - but does not increment the address. I'm not that familiar with Masm/Tasm syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using BIOS [int 10h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call#Invoking_an_interrupt):

```
mov ah, 0eh
mov al, 'A'
int 10h
```

Using DOS [int 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02):

```
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 'A'
int 21h
```